# Mule zip file is corrupt after dumping in directory with file outbound endpoint

Tags: file, zip, mule

I have a file inbound endpoint with a zip file coming in. If an error occurs during the flow I use a file outbound endpoint with the output pattern

```
[message.outboundProperties.originalFileName]
```

The zip file is then corrupt and cannot be opened by windows. The zip file has also increased in size. Anyone know whats going on?

The code

```
</spring:beans>

<file:connector name="fileConnectorNonStreaming"
    autoDelete="true" doc:name="File" streaming="false"
    validateConnections="true">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.file.FileMuleMessageFactory" />
</file:connector>

<smtp:connector name="SMTP" validateConnections="true"
    doc:name="SMTP" />

<file:connector name="fileStreamingConnector"
    autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true"
    doc:name="File" />

<custom-transformer class="org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString"
    name="ObjectToStringTransformer" doc:name="Java"></custom-transformer>

<jdbc:connector name="JDBC" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source"
    validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0"
    doc:name="JDBC">
    <jdbc:query key="commitFileNames"
        value="insert into ${sta.database.source.table} (NAME, REF, DATE, TIME, DESCRIPTION) values (#[message.payload[0].toString()], #[message.payload[1].toString()], (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#[message.payload[2].toString()], '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) , #[message.payload[3].toString()], #[message.payload[4].toString()]) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE S_FILENAME = #[message.payload[0].toString()], S_DEBTREF = #[message.payload[1].toString()], S_DATE = (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#[message.payload[2].toString()], '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')), S_TIME = #[message.payload[3].toString()] ,S_DESCRIPTION = #[message.payload[4].toString()]" />
</jdbc:connector>

<jdbc:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source"
    user="root" password="root" url="${database.mysql.url}${database.schema}"
    transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source" />

<flow name="getfilenames" doc:name="getfilenames">

    <file:inbound-endpoint doc:name="File"
        responseTimeout="10000" path="${csv.zipped.files}" connector-ref="fileConnectorNonStreaming"
        fileAge="2000"></file:inbound-endpoint>     

    <set-variable variableName="unzippedFilesDestinationPath"
        value="${csv.unzipped.files.archive}" doc:name="Store the path of the target file to be unzipped" />    

    <set-variable variableName="targetFileName" value="${file.compressed.name}"
        doc:name="Store the file name of the target file to be unzipped" />

    <component class="com.mule.file.FileDeleter"
        doc:name="Delete unzipped file from directory" />       

    <set-variable variableName="sourceZipFile" value="#[payload]"
        doc:name="Store the incoming zip file" />       

    <component class="com.mule.file.ZipDeCompressor"
        doc:name="Unzip and aquire target csv file" />      

    <set-variable variableName="unzippedFile" value="#[payload]"
        doc:name="Store the unzipped file" />       

    <component class="com.influentialsoftware.sta.mule.csv.CsvParser"
        doc:name="Parse CSV and validate" />        

    <foreach doc:name="For Each">

        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="commitFileNames"
            connector-ref="JDBC" doc:name="Insert data" exchange-pattern="one-way"
            queryTimeout="-1"></jdbc:outbound-endpoint>

    </foreach>      

    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">

        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy"
            when="#[exception.causedBy(java.io.IOException)]">

            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${file.base.directory.errors}"
                outputPattern="#[message.outboundProperties.originalFileName]"
                responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="fileStreamingConnector"
                doc:name="toError"></file:outbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: Flow configuration or we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FileMuleMessageFactory in fileConnectorNonStreaming sets the payload to File, while your output would prefer a byte array. Try adding a `<file:file-to-byte-array-transformer />` before your file:outbound-endpoint.